# Perl script to parse JSON data

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to create a script to parse JSON content but it is not working:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl-w
use DBI;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Simple;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use Data::Dumper;
use DateTime;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $req = new HTTP::Request GET => 'https://google.com/pub/';
my $res = $ua->request($req);
my $contents = $res->content;
##json response:

#{"success":true,"data":"{\"campaign\":\"21490|\",\"format\":\"md5  \",\"delta_timestamp\":\"1528992718\",\"result\":\"success\",\"download_link\":\"https:\\\/\\\/gmail.net\\\/accesskey\\\/getfile\\\/m-spqn-e61-2aef2575a0b5250354f2b0fda033e703?token=HUSYjdC5jyJskXUHiKn13l1A1BaAjH2R&dcma=e8fae90c472ae146\"}","message":null}

print $contents;

#Check the outcome of the Response
if ( $res->is_success ) {
print $res->content;
}


# Decode the main json object
my $jsn = decode_json($res);

# Since 'data' is another serialized object, you need to decode that as well:
my $data = decode_json($jsn);

# Now you can access the contents of 'data'
#want to extract download_link object
print $data->{'download_url'};
```

I am looking at the content of `download_link`.

Comment: You should actually print out your object and ensure it matches the form you think it does. Just glancing at the commented out object it would suggest that your variable `$data` doesn't have a key "download_url".

Comment: `$res` is an HTTP::Response object, not a JSON string!

Comment: Your question is not clear/poorly phrased (I have edited it). You are not showing your current errors. You speak about "download_link" but your code uses "download_url". Your script starts with "perl-w" which is probably a typo for "perl -w" and in which case the `-w` is useless as you have `use warnings;` (as recommended) below.

Comment: Do **NOT** use this form: `new HTTP::Request`, use instead `HTTP::Request->new()`

Answer (score 3):

```
use JSON qw(decode_json);

# from $res->content
my $content = '{"success":true,"data":"{\"campaign\":\"21490|\",\"format\":\"md5  \",\"delta_timestamp\":\"1528992718\",\"result\":\"success\",\"download_link\":\"https:\\\/\\\/gmail.net\\\/accesskey\\\/getfile\\\/m-spqn-e61-2aef2575a0b5250354f2b0fda033e703?token=HUSYjdC5jyJskXUHiKn13l1A1BaAjH2R&dcma=e8fae90c472ae146\"}","message":null}';

print decode_json(decode_json($content)->{data})->{download_link};
```